# custom updated_at field doesn't work cataloginventory_stock_item current_timestamp

Tags: php, magento, timestamp, field, addition

I added an extra field to `cataloginventory_stock_item` to update to current time when stock changes:

```
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

          $installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
          $installer->startSetup();
          $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(

          $installer->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_item'),
            'updated_time',
            'TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE NOW() NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()'

          ); 
        $installer->endSetup();
```

But when the qty is changed in magento the field doesn't update to the current timestamps (but the qty does change).

I also tried creating a field using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `NOW()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe ON UPDATE behaviour will only be triggered by MySQL if you don't provide a value for that column, due to the way Magento models work with Varien_Object, the value loaded from the database will get posted when you save the model. If you wish to have this updated your best bet will probably be to register an observer for cataloginventory_stock_item_before_save, and use setData to make updated_time the current time before it get's saved into the database.

Comment: as an aside, if you look through the structure of the Magento database, you will see that several tables have ON UPDATE behaviours on fields called created_at, and not on the updated_at ***facepalm***.

Answer (score 1):

You could update the model's `updated_time` data value just before saving the model by listening for the `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to make this work:

```
$item->setUpdatedAt(0);
```

Not too different from setting the timestamp manually, but it is left up to the database to set it.

If it's a custom model you can also do the following in the model:

```
protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $model)
{
    $model->setUpdatedAt(0);
}
```